# What is the preferred syntax for declaring an array in VB.NET?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Between the following options, which is the preferred syntax for declaring arrays in VB.NET?

1. `Dim numbers1() As Integer`

   vs.
2. `Dim numbers2 As Integer()`

The MSDN article [How to: Initialize an Array Variable in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx) mentions the second option as the preferred syntax: `Dim chars2 As Char()...`, but the first option seems more common in other documentation. The second option might be confusing since it's so similar to calling a constructor with no arguments.

E.g.

`Dim customer As New Customer() ' Initialize a new Customer`

which looks similar to:

`Dim customer As Customer() ' An uninitialized array of Customers`

This question is similar to but different from: [Different ways of declaring arrays in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630679/different-ways-of-declaring-arrays-in-vb-net).

Comment: This is a broad question and also has been a long debatable question before. `preferred syntax` that itself **depends**... `Dim numbers1() As Integer` I would use this to specify the array bounds for example `Dim numbers1(5) As Integer` and the other if I don't know what the bounds could be. To be honest `Dim numbers1() As Integer` and this `Dim numbers2 As Integer()` are the same, no difference...they are both arrays that don't have a bounds (limit).

Comment: @Zaggler strictly speaking `Dim n(5) As Int32` isn't a declaration anymore it's an initialization and so should be outside the scope of the question. That said there is no more advantage of using that first syntax (AFAIK the only other place where first version is possible is for argument declaration) and more, the second is consistent with other use of "array declaration" (as return type for properties or functions, as generic parameter etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I just found the [Visual Basic Coding Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx) on MSDN which states, "Put the array designator on the type, not on the variable" (e.g. `Dim letters4 As String()`).

Answer (score 1):

I'll chime in here.

I've seen more of style 1 in code than style two, however there are some minor odd inconsistencies with syntax when it comes to properties.

My theory is the reason the parentheses after is preferred is to make it more consistent with declaring a property that is an array

```
Public Property x As Integer() 'is an array
Public Property y() As Integer 'is NOT an array
```

That being said...use Lists :)